# Epson Stylus Photo RX620 printer not working after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: printing

My Epson Stylus Photo RX620 printer was working fine under 18.04, but not under 20.04.  "Select Printer Driver" does not list the printer (the only Stylus Photo model is 750, without even the RX).  The error shown against each job in the print queue is "There is a missing print filter for printer 'Epson-Stylus-Photo-RX620-2'".

Is it going to be possible to get printing working to this printer again, or does it mean buying a new printer?

Edited to add: originally the printer was connected to a remote machine and accessed via a "Raw" (port 9100) server that I wrote, which is unidirectional and there's no SNMP service on that machine.  I connected the printer instead, directly to the Ubuntu box.  The box saw it and offered to install a Gutenprint driver for it.  Promising, I thought.

The symptoms now are that all the print jobs complete, but the printer does nothing.  It doesn't even wake out of its on-but-no-display state, so the printer driver can't be sending anything to the printer at all.

The ink levels can't be read either.

So I'm further on, but no better off.

(My "Raw" server saw no incoming data either.  There would have been a log entry if it had.)

Comment: Install Epson Linux drivers. https://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX

Comment: Those Linux drivers are at least 9 years old!  Aren't they 32-bit?

Comment: That's true. They are 32-bit and not in a deb format. It seems that Epson has dropped support.

Comment: 18.04 (which I used until 2 days ago) was 64-bit, so there was a working 64-bit solution for the RX620 within the 18.04 distro.  Has it been deliberately dropped, or has it stopped working because of a bug somewhere?

Comment: I am assuming the printer is still USB connected. Give what you get for `lpinfo -v`.

Comment: david@LinuxBox:~$ lpinfo -v  

network beh  
file cups-brf:/  
network lpd  
network ipps  
network ipp  
network socket  
network http  
network https  
direct hp  
direct usb://EPSON/Stylus%20Photo%20RX620?serial=L70040503081448370&amp;interface=1  
direct hpfax  
david@LinuxBox:~$

Comment: My apologies to all who're reading.  I can't find how to preserve line breaks in the comment above.  Markdown doesn't appear to be obeyed.

Answer (score 0):

`lpinfo -v` gives you a URI.

> usb://EPSON/Stylus%20Photo%20RX620?serial=L70040503081448370&interface=1

`lpinfo -m | grep RX620` will give you a PPD. **Substitute** for the URI and the PPD in

`lpadmin -p rx620 -v URI -E -m PPD`

Test printing with `lp -d rx620 /etc/nsswitch.conf`.

Ok now?

Comment: lpinfo -m | grep RX620 gives nothing in this 20.04 system.

I'm going to try it on a laptop I have that's still running 18.04 and see if I can get a file that I can copy over and will work.  

And, curiously, that usb:// line no longer appears in the output of lpinfo -v

Comment: D'oh - the printer has to be turned on for the usb:: URI to appear...

Comment: Still not OK, but I need to understand what my "gutenprint.5.2://etc" URI means as a source for the PPD file.  I still get nothing on this 20.04 system from "lpinfo -M | grep RX620".  On the laptop I get "gutenprint.5.2://escp2-rx620/expert Epson Stylus Photo RX620 - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.13"

Comment: Install printer-driver-gutenprint. I forgot. It is not on 20.04 by default as it is on 18.04.

Comment: Made it in the end.  I did wonder whether I should install Gutenprint.  Your confirmation made me do it.  Installation of gutenprint was of course easy.  Installation of the printer was not.  One way into the settings just gets into an infinite loop when looking for a printer driver.  Fortunately there are two ways, and the other way works.  The other issue was that adding a new printer (I opted to delete the old one) gave me one named CUPS-BRF-Printer that steadfastly ignored my commands to rename it.  I had to stop cups, edit /etc/cups/printers.conf and restart cups to get the name right.

Comment: Installation of the printer is simplicity itself with the guidance I gave.

Comment: It was in 18.04.  It should be, and it's not your fault that it wasn't in 20.04.  Maybe future updates to 20.04 will fix the couple of bugs I found along the way.  Importantly, thank you for encouraging me to install Gutenprint.

Comment: A late postscript: the next time I tried to print, it no longer worked.  I couldn't delete the printer driver because Ubuntu claimed it couldn't find it.  (It's there; you're showing it to me!...)  Eventually I used apt-get to remove and re-install the whole printing system and add the printer again.  Since then it's been fine.